# DCOM calling process in remote target

Tags: com, dcom, remote-process

so consider that a process in one computer tries to call a method of an interface in another process in another computer.

How does DCOM knows that the process can be instantiated on a remote computer and afterwards actually instantiate that object/class in the remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

The remote host is mentioned [in the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678423.aspx), via `RemoteServerName` value under `AppId` key.

Or, you could specify it programmatically, by means of `COSERVERINFO` parameter to `CoCreateInstanceEx`.